# How to add ROW_NUMBER() in a view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, row-number

In PostgreSQL 8.4 I want to create a view from 3 tables with id. So I want to have this structure in my view:

```
num serial,
name_dispatcher character varying(250)
the_geom geometry
```

I can select `name_dispatcher` and `the_geom` from tables:

```
 CREATE VIEW lineView
      AS SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
      FROM line1
      UNION
      SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
      FROM line2
      UNION
      SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
      FROM line3
```

How to create the `num` column in the view?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lineView.voltage)
```

But I don't know how to use it in `ALTER VIEW`. How do I put it in there?

Comment: Side note: Be aware that `UNION` can be an expensive operation, because it eliminates duplicates. If you know that no duplicates will be in your final result, or you're okay with duplicates existing, switching to `UNION ALL` may be beneficial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `ALTER VIEW` to drop or add columns. I quote [the manual on ALTER VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterview.html):

> `ALTER VIEW` changes various auxiliary properties of a view. (If you
>   want to modify the view's defining query, use `CREATE OR REPLACE
>   VIEW`.)

But a simple `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` won't cut it. [Another quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html):

> The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by
>   the existing view query

So `DROP` and `CREATE` the view:

```
DROP VIEW lineview;

CREATE VIEW lineview AS
SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ???) AS num
FROM (
   SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
   FROM line1

   UNION
   SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
   FROM line2

   UNION
   SELECT 'name' AS name_dispatcher, the_geom
   FROM line3
   ) x
```

I use a subquery because I assume you want to add `row_number()` to all rows. Your question is vague in that respect.
If you just want a unique id in no particular order, use `row_number() OVER()`.

Comment: @KliverMax: That's short for `AS x` and is a table alias for the sub-select. SQL requires one.