# How to add an ordinal id field based on a sort order in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, row-number

I was wondering how to add a field to a table (e.g. `country`) based on sorting some of its fields (e.g. `ISO` code)?

I searched around SO and found the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table), but the solution is based on MySQL. I tried to use the solution there in Postgres 9.3 and it's giving me an syntax error on `:=`. What I tried is:

```
SELECT  l.*,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    country l ORDER BY ISO
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
```

How to adapt this to Postgres?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394002/how-to-add-row-number-in-a-view

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394002 because I am asking about adding id to one table based on **sorted order**. The other question is technically about assigning an id to a view of union of tables. Sorting wasn't in the question though it's possible. The concerns are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT   country.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY iso)
FROM     country
ORDER BY iso
```